# Keep middle datatable column value and delete others

Tags: c#, datatable

I have a `DataTable` C# that has the following columns:

[image]

I want to keep only one "**Category**" value that is very next to the middle of the total rows by group "**Category**".

Here is an example of what I want to accomplish.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I could solve it.

Here is the code, maybe is not the most elegant solution but works.

```
List<int> rowIndexes = new List<int>();

                    DataView viewCategories = new DataView(ds.Tables["data"]);
                    DataTable dtCategories = viewCategories.ToTable(true, "categorytype");

                    // format datatable
                    for(int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < ds.Tables["data"].Rows.Count; rowIndex++)
                    {
                        DataRow dr = ds.Tables["data"].Rows[rowIndex];

                        if (rowIndex < ds.Tables["data"].Rows.Count - 1)
                        {
                            DataRow drNext = ds.Tables["data"].Rows[rowIndex + 1];

                            if (dr["categorytype"].ToString() != drNext["categorytype"].ToString())
                            {
                                rowIndexes.Add(rowIndex);
                            }
                        }   
                    }

                    int index = 0;
                    // insert empty rows
                    foreach(int rowIndex in rowIndexes)
                    {
                        index++;

                        DataRow newRow = ds.Tables["data"].NewRow();

                        ds.Tables["data"].Rows.InsertAt(newRow, rowIndex + index);
                        ds.Tables["data"].AcceptChanges();
                    }


                    // clean categories and keep only one
                    foreach (DataRow dr in dtCategories.Rows)
                    {
                        DataView view = ds.Tables["data"].DefaultView;
                        view.RowFilter = "categorytype = '" + dr["categorytype"].ToString() + "'";

                        if (view.Count > 1)
                        {
                            int mid = (int)Math.Floor((double)view.Count / (double)2);

                            index = 0;

                            foreach(DataRowView drView in view)
                            {
                                if (index != mid) drView["categorytype"] = string.Empty;
                                index++;
                            }


                            ds.Tables["data"].AcceptChanges();


                        }
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough rep to ask questions, so, without knowing what UI output you are trying to achieve, e.g. datagrid, or Razor, or Excel, etc. - you can populate your data table in SQL with the row number that is supposed to contain category name, like this:

```html
  select category,invoice,amount,tax,total, 0 as ccount into #temp from test
  update #temp set ccount = (select round(cast(count(category) as decimal)/2.0,0) from test where category=#temp.category group by test.category)

  select * from #temp
  drop table #temp
```

This will give you the resulting datatable:

[image]

Then, as you loop through the rows, if the row number matches "ccount", print the category name.

Answer (score 0):

```
//dt is DataTable
foreach (var category in dt.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(g => g.Field<string>("Category")))
{
    var rows = category.OrderBy(o => o.Field<int>("Invoice")).ToArray();
    foreach (DataRow row in rows.Where((w, i) => i != (rows.Length-1) / 2))
    {
        row["Category"] = "";
    }
}
```

or SQL if can be used

```
SELECT CASE WHEN 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Category ORDER BY Invoice) 
= ((COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Category)+1)/2)  
THEN Category ELSE '' END,
Invoice, Amount, Tax, Total
FROM DataTable
ORDER BY Invoice
```